# Excluding extent when polygonizing raster file using Python?

Tags: python, polygon, extents, raster-conversion

I want to polygonize a raster file. The raster file looks like this.

Here is the  [raster file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19KoX6bqGg5WPWg6tvWIJBb0nYgsTeHqC/view?usp=sharing)

[image: raster]

Here is my codes in Python to polygonize the raster file. The codes source from [Polygonize a Raster Band](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#polygonize-a-raster-band)

```
#raster to polygons

from osgeo import gdal, ogr

#  get raster datasource


src_ds = gdal.Open( "C:\\Users\\select3.tif" )

srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

#  create output datasource

dst_layername = "output_select3"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
#The following two steps are very important, otherwise will generate error like (Coordinate not defined)
dst_ds.Destroy()
src_ds=None
```

I got the result which looks like this.

And here is the [output shapefile](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LnuAgGpNLID4VTz2M5qk11C8ryxZpUhq?usp=sharing)
 [image: Polygons]

I do not satisfy with this, because I only want to have the polygon areas (Check mark) and **exclude the extent (Cross mark)** of the polygons. Could anybody tell me how to fix this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you don't need a mask for that task, but RGB values of the polygon areas equals 0. So you need to change them into a value (for example 125) and to change others into 0. Since all bands have same value, so it's sufficient to change one band to polygonize the raster as you did.

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

src_ds = gdal.Open( "C:\\Users\\select3.tif" )
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# Invert pixel value to use srcband as a mask.
numpy_band = srcband.ReadAsArray() ##
numpy_band[numpy_band<125] = 125   ##
numpy_band[numpy_band>125] = 0     ##
srcband.WriteArray(numpy_band)     ##

dst_layername = "C:\\Users\\mask.tif"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, srcband, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )  ##
dst_ds.Destroy()
src_ds=None
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by applying a mask as the second argument in the Polygonize function, as stated in the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) documentation. The mask needs to be a separate raster layer, that has 0 where you **don't** want the algorithm to polygonize.

With your data, follow these steps to implement:

1) Run raster calculator on your original raster ("select3.tif") with this expression to set the value of the areas you want to 1, and all the rest to 0:

[image]

2) Edit your code with these lines:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

#  get raster datasource
src_ds = gdal.Open( "C:\\Users\\select3.tif" )
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

mask_ds = gdal.Open( "C:\\Users\\mask.tif" ) #Path to the mask layer generated above
maskband = mask_ds.GetRasterBand(1) 

#  create output datasource
dst_layername = "output_select3"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, maskband, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None ) #Mask's band as second argument in Polygonize function

dst_ds.Destroy()
src_ds=None
```

Result:

[image]